# How to get started with OpenCv on Raspberry-Pi

Tags: raspbian, opencv, c++

I have just installed the OpenCV (2.4.8) on my Raspberry-pi working on raspbian using these steps [from this blog entry](http://robertcastle.com/2014/02/installing-opencv-on-a-raspberry-pi/).

I can find the cmake in the applications but not the opencv what is the next steps to start working C++ ?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Some more detail about what you have actually tried would help. Did you actually get to the point of running `sudo make install` for example? Did the command run successfully or spew forth errors? Etc.

Comment: I did everything till sudo make install anf i added /usr/local/lib  in sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf and in sudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH               but i dont have the file build

Comment: What do you mean by "file build" ?

Comment: Do you mean the compiled libraries of OpenCV?